# Browse Android SQLite with Datagrip

Tags: android, android-sqlite, datagrip

I'm new to Android and I have been trying to connect my SQLite db with DataGrip (because I already use it and I feel confortable with it). 
I wanted to try  [this way](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/accessing-android-sqllite-databases-from-product.html) but dropdown didn't show any Android SQLite option.

I also tried [this way](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/managing-data-sources.html#creating_db_by_drag_and_drop), but I couldn't find the .db file in my Android project.

Any help will be nice, thanks!

Comment: DataGrip does not have data source type for Android devices since it does not have Android support. It is only available in IntelliJ IDEA or AndroidStudio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way that is maybe a bit tricky and not helpful at all, but at least I can browse into the db:

- Enter the Device File Explorer on Android Studio
- Copy the database you need into your local folder (path is data/data//database.db)
- Then enter datagrip and create a new data source (SQLite), using this file.

It's a really anoying way, because each time you make any changes, you need to re-copy the file, and sync your datasource. But anyway, it works.